# Why is this set a subset of its polyhedral approximation - contradicting the gradient inequality?

Tags: inequality, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Say we have a set

$C:= \{y\in \mathbb{R}^n : g_i(y) \leq 0, \space i=1,...,m\}$

where $g_i : \mathbb{R}^n \to 
\mathbb{R}$ are convex and differentiable functions, then we have

$\tilde C : = \{y: g_i(x) + \langle \nabla g_i(x),y-x \rangle \leq 0, i=1,...,m\}$,

the polyhedral approximation of $C$.

Then why is it that $\tilde C \supset  C $ ?

According to the gradient inequality:
$g(y) \geq g(x) + \langle \nabla g(x),y-x \rangle $, then doesn't this imply that $\tilde C \subset C$ ?

Comment: Take an example. Consider $\mathbb{R}^n=\mathbb{R}^1$. Let $m=1$ and let $g_1(x) = x^2 -1$. Then $C= [-1,1]$, right? That's because $g_1(x)>0$ whenever $|x|>1$. Now let $x=0$. Then $\nabla g_1(x) = 0$ and $g_1(x)=-1$, so $\tilde{C}$ is actucally all of $\mathbb{R}$ and we have $C\subset \tilde{C}$. Now take some non-zero $x\in(-1,1)$ and draw a diagram. You'll see $C\subset \tilde{C}$. Then stare at the definitions of $C$ and $\tilde{C}$ and your gradient inequality. Observe  $y\in C$ implies $g_i(y)\le 0$ implies $g(x)+(\nabla g_i(x),y-x)\le 0$ implies $y\in\tilde{C}$.